# Excessive empathy, social cues and adaptive behavior evaluation

Tags: social-psychology, emotion, abnormal-psychology, empathy

An article by Gunnar Bartsch of  Julius-Maximilians-Universität Würzburg, JMU started me on this line of inquiry.

The [original source](https://www.uni-wuerzburg.de/en/sonstiges/meldungen/detail/artikel/wie-wir-andere-verstehen-1) is no longer available but has been reproduced at [ScienceDaily](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/04/160428094950.htm) (Bartsch, n.d.)

We generally accept the concept of Compassion Fatigue and Secondary Trauma as an individual choosing to over-do it with regard to empathy and hence the recommendation of better boundaries and self care. I have many studies...saying our Aspergers and ADHD kids have problem with social skills because of low empathy what if the kid falls at the high empathy end of the spectrum?

What research is being done in psychology and/or neuroscience regarding excessive empathy and altruism as a condition and the resulting adaptive behavior patterns? I want to know more.

### References

Bartsch, G. (n.d.) Excessive empathy can impair understanding of others. *ScienceDaily*. Retrieved from https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/04/160428094950.htm